# Custom object detection model to TensorFlow Lite, shape of model input

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite, object-detection-api

I need to export a **custom** object detection model, fine-tuned on a custom dataset, to TensorFlow Lite, so that it can run on Android devices.

I'm using TensorFlow 2.4.1 on Ubuntu 18.04, and so far this is what I did:

1. fine-tuned an 'ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpnlite_640x640_coco17_tpu-8' model, using a dataset of new images. I used the 'model_main_tf2.py' script from the repository;
2. I exported the model using 'exporter_main_v2.py'

```
python exporter_main_v2.py --input_type image_tensor --pipeline_config_path .\models\custom_model\pipeline.config --trained_checkpoint_dir .\models\custom_model\ --output_directory .\exported-models\custom_model
```

which produced a Saved Model (.pb file);
3. I tested the exported model for inference, and everything works fine. In the detection routine, I used:

```py
def get_model_detection_function(model):
##Get a tf.function for detection

    @tf.function
    def detect_fn(image):
        """Detect objects in image."""
        image, shapes = model.preprocess(image)
        prediction_dict = model.predict(image, shapes)
        detections = model.postprocess(prediction_dict, shapes)
        return detections, prediction_dict, tf.reshape(shapes, [-1])
    return detect_fn
```

and the shape of the produced image object is 640x640, as expected.

Then, I tried to convert this .pb model to tflite.
After updating to the nightly version of tensorflow (with the normal version, I got an error), I was actually able to produce a .tflite file by using this code:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tflite_support import metadata as _metadata

saved_model_dir = 'exported-models/custom_model/'

## Convert the model
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(saved_model_dir)
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
converter.experimental_new_converter = True
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [
    tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS, tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS]
tflite_model = converter.convert()

# Save the model.
with open('tflite/custom_model.tflite', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(tflite_model)
```

I tried to use this model in AndroidStudio, following the instructions given [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/running_on_mobile_tf2.md).

However, I'm getting a couple of errors:

1. something regarding 'Not a valid Tensorflow lite model' (have to check better on this);
2. the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot copy to a TensorFlowLite tensor (serving_default_input_tensor:0) with 3 bytes from a Java Buffer with 270000 bytes.
```

The second error seems to indicate there's something weird with the input expected from the tflite model.
I examined the file with Netron, and this is what I got:

[image: Netron]

the input is expected to have...1x1x1x3 shape, or am I misinterpreting the graph?
Should I somehow set the tensor input size when using the tflite exporter?

Anyway, what is the right way to export my custom model so that it can run on Android?

Answer (score 0):

TF Ops are supported via the Flex delegate. I bet that is the problem. If you want to check if it is that, you can do:

1. Download benchmark app with flex delegate support for TF Ops. You can find it here, in the section `Native benchmark binary`: https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/measurement. For example, for android is https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow-nightly-public/prod/tensorflow/release/lite/tools/nightly/latest/android_aarch64_benchmark_model_plus_flex
2. Connect your phone to your computer and where you have downloaded the apk, do `adb push <apk_name> /data/local/tmp`
3. Push your model `adb push <tflite_model> /data/local/tmp`
4. Open shell `adb shell` and go to folder `cd /data/local/tmp`. Then run the app with `./<apk_name> --graph=<tflite_model>`

Info from:

- https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/ops_select
- https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/measurement